# Listening: Though today I have to live OR leave

Tags: lyrics, listening

Here's the music video on YouTube: [Dan Byrd - Sayonara Means Goodbye](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fFd23_FWWwQ), specifically at [:33](https://youtu.be/fFd23_FWWwQ?t=33).
And here's the lyrics I found on [LyricsFreak](https://www.lyricsfreak.com/d/dan+byrd/sayonara_20892998.html):

> Sayonara means goodbye
>   Sayonara one more cry
>   Though today I have to live
>   I still want you to believe

I'm not sure if the lyrics are OK. For example:

> Though today I have to *live*

I think it's *leave*.

Comment: @KentaroTomono: "Didn't the OP ask about the whole lyrics for proof reading?" I'm an English learner and I'm just working on my "listening" skill. I simply wonder if I got the music right or not, especially the part the admin highlighted. That's exactly why we English learners are here. Thanks Em.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do a web search for 'lyrics sayonara means goodbye' you'll find a lot of sites giving the lyrics. They all (the 5 or so I checked) have *live* and not *leave*. However, these sites are quite often sourced by random internet people - that is, they do not have any 'official' status.

The only way to find out, I think, is to find out who the publisher is, and then ask them. This may involve buying a copy of the sheet music.

Personally, without listening to it myself, I think *leave* makes marginally more sense in the songs context (repeating the word from the first verse and rhyming with *believe*) - but I know nothing.

Comment: The answer makes perfect sense.  Plus, listening to the song, it's clear the word is "leave".

Answer (score 3):

Dan Byrd's singing is unclear, but from context, "leave" makes the most sense.

First, the song is about saying goodbye (leaving). "I have to leave" is a common thing to say to a loved one when you would rather stay with them but are forced to go away.

Second, the rhyming pattern of the verses is strong evidence for "leave". Throughout the song you have rhyming groups such as:

> goodbye/cry
>
> leave/believe
>
> live/give
>
> try/by
>
> fine/sign/mine

Rhyming "live" with "give" later in the song is also good evidence that "leave" is correct in the second verse.